# Get message updates from a private group using telegram bot

Tags: bots, telegram

I joined a private telegram group, I want to get message updates from this group.

I can create a bot but I can't add my bot to this group.

I checked various sources, all tells that bot needs to be in that group to be able to get updates.

Is there a chance that I get my messages from that private group that I joined but my bot not.

I intend to do that using python.

Comment: probably duplicated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/67601702/5655675

Comment: I found telethon library, its in python and provides user api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Telegram Bot API this way.

But you can use User API to get messages.
E.g.: https://docs.pyrogram.org/